# proper use of std::vector.push_back() with a user defined type

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm getting segmentation faults (I think) with my current method of vector.push_back().

Here is some example code:

So I have my class Zombie

```
class Zombie
{
    public:
       Zombie();
       ~Zombie();

       SDL_Surface* image;

       SDL_Rect box;

       bool dead;

   protected:

   private:
       // gets random coordinates around the screen
       SDL_Rect get_zombie_rect();
 };
```

with the constructor being:

```
Zombie::Zombie()
   :
   dead(false),
   image(load_image("Player.png")),
   box(get_zombie_rect())
{

}
```

and Zombie has a handler class to manage the vector with a function called create_new_zombie(). (here is the problem)

```
void Zombie_Manager::create_new_zombie()
{
   Zombie newZombie;
   zombies.push_back(newZombie);
}
```

Is this the correct way to add an element to a vector?

I'm able to get a working version with the use of pointers, but there has to be an easier and more correct way of accomplishing this, right?

Why am I getting a seg fault if std::vector.push_back() shallow copies its new elements? Am I wrong in assuming that?

Comment: I hope you realize that `image` is uninitialized garbage.

Comment: How to implement a copy constructor: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: I don't think every question that is answered by the answer to another question is a duplicate, is it?

Comment: @Chris : I think it is when the other question is a FAQ.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to implement a copy constructor and an assignment operator.

`zombies.push_back(newZombie);` pushes a copy of `newZombie` in the vector. When the method enters, the original `newZombie` is destroyed. And I'm willing to bet that in `~Zombie()` you call `delete image;`.

Because you don't have a proper copy constructor and assignment operator, all copies will be invalid, because they will contain dangling pointer.

Always follow the **rule of three** - if you need to implement a destructor, you also need to implement a c-ctor and assignment operator.

Comment: And since the object contains raw pointers it will need to be a *deep* copy. Or better yet use a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Why doesn't the compiler implement one for us?

Comment: @0A0D it does, but it does a shallow copy. The pointer `image` in the copy points to the same location as the original one. So when the original one is destroyed, the pointer in the copy will be dangling.

Comment: Considering this is SDL we're talking about, I don't think there's an actual `delete` anywhere. Anyhow, a dangling pointer *is* very likely the problem. If C++11 is an option, I'd recommend also implementing a move constructor to be able to efficiently use STL containers (without resorting to storing pointers in any form).